# backup mysql database in php using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, that uses mysqldump to backup mysql database. The problem is I'm getting this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   60 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\wamp\www\pos\php\backupdb.php on
>   line 13

Line 13 is the final line.

```
<?php
$backupFile = 'c:\\onstor'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -u root -p onstor > $backupFile";
system($command);
?>
```

What do I do, I think the code is okay since I've tried it in command prompt and it worked.
Is it bad that I have put the path to mysql/bin to the environment variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131959/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-400-seconds-exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as the error message states pretty plainly, is that your script is running for too long. Scripts executing through a web server are not meant to run longer than a few seconds. You can change that using [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), but what you should really do is let long running scripts run from the command line. Since the only thing you're doing is running a CLI command anyway, just ditch the PHP wrapper completely. Make it a shell script if necessary. Run this shell script regularly as a cron job/Windows Scheduler task (or whatever the Windows equivalent is called).

Comment: where do I have to put this set_time_limit?at the end of the php.ini? or in the file itself?

Comment: at the beginning of the dump module. Putting it in php.ini will apply for all projects. Also, putting in your common controller (the file which runs for all modules) will apply for all your modules which is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay. Dumping is taking lot of time. that's all. Read this [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 400 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131959/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-400-seconds-exceeded/2132008#2132008). Do what is written there first and then look for any problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The message say you reached out the 60 seconds excution time.

You can change it using the [`set_time_limit`](http://fr.php.net/set_time_limit) function, i.e.:

```
 set_time_limit(120); // 2 minutes
```

but I don't know why you would try to use `mysqldump` in PHP, it seems dangerous to me.

Comment: @RageZ how is it dangerous? Can you explain a little. PhpMyAdmin allows data dump too.

Comment: @Sandeepan: if you use some browser to do your dump, it means you have to give enough privilege to your webserver to write the dump in some directory. If that directory is inside your server root it means the whole world can download the dump. phpMyAdmin provide such function but I think it takes some securities measure around it, like deleting the dump when you finished downloading and so on...

Comment: @Sandeepan: plus you have to be have a login/password to use phpmysql that probably not the case for your page or at least it's up to you.

Comment: Now that may be a different issue. Is it taking time (to dump)? Ask a separate question better

Comment: @Sandeepan: it would read your entire database and make a file of it, so yes it would take time if you have thousands of rows. I don't think you have to create one more question ;-)

Comment: @RageZ - I am asking if it is taking time to know if the dump query is executing. If it is executing and no time out happening but still 0 KB file, then probably some other issue. This question was asked with the timeout issue.

Comment: @Sandeepan: sorry I misunderstood, yes it might be sometime out, since the webserver would kill the process running php and then the mysqldump process at the same time.